# I can't break this while loop

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I have an assignment where I need to complete an action until the input is 'quit', 'Quit', 'q', or 'Q'. I've been trying this:

```
while variable != 'quit' or 'Quit' or 'q' or 'Q':
    # do stuff
```

however when any of those strings are inputted the while loop still executes! I've tried other ways like if statements but it just times out. How can I break the loop correctly?

Comment: You need to express each condition explicitly like `while variable != 'quit' and variable != 'QUIT' and`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is probably something like this:

```
while str(variable).upper() not in ['QUIT', 'Q']:
```

This way, you can list all the values which allow the user to quit in one place and the case (upper or lower) is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you have something like the following:

```
while variable != 'quit' or 'Quit' or 'q' or 'Q':
    # do stuff
    variable = input("")
```

(By the way - welcome to Stack Overflow! As another user has mentioned in a comment - please provide a code example; it will help potential answerers actually know what's going wrong and what you're trying to do.)

The reason why it never breaks is because what the Python interpreter actually sees is:

```
while (variable != 'quit') or ('Quit') or ('q') or ('Q'):
    # do stuff
    variable = input("")
```

In Python, non-empty strings will evaluate to true - if you try `bool('q')` in the Python interpreter, you will get `True`. This means that the interpreter is running:

```
while (variable != 'quit') or True or True or True:
    # do stuff
    variable = input("")
```

which obviously never breaks. What you need to do is check all options; Kind Stranger has one solution but more explicitly, you could try

```
while variable not in ('quit', 'Quit', 'q', 'Q'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 while (variable != "quit" and variable != "q"  and variable != "Q" and variable != "Quit"):
```

You cannot do variable != "q" or "Q" etc.

Comment: This loop won't break because at least one of these conditions will always be true regardless of the value of `variable`